# Show Button Only When External File Exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this button in my show.blade file:

```
<a href="https://www.externaldomain.com/downloads/{{ $book->slug }}.pdf" class="badge badge-primary" style="width:100%;padding:10px;font-size:12px;margin-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
```

I want to show this download button only when href file exist in externaldomain. Otherwise it should not load/show this button. Please suggest me a simple code that i should paste instead of the above code.

**Note:** I am using this code on `mydomain.com` and file stored in `outsidedomain.com`.

Comment: Does your PHP code check if the file exists before passing the information onto the blade?

Comment: No, it does not. Actually I am using a readymade script and want to add a custom download/open-book button on the book view page. My PDF files are stored on other website and i want to use those files for download button. When i have pdf on other website with that href="https://www.externaldomain.com/downloads/{{ $book->slug }}.pdf" it should show download button and if there is no pdf file on that href, then it should not show button.

Comment: better show full code otherwise we might predict in different ways.So it help some one to answer easily

Comment: I can't exactly decide which code I should paste here. But if I simplify my questions "I want a simple Javascript Function that will load/hide a button on the basis of the href file, if file exist, it should show the button, if not exist it should hide the button"

Comment: @QasimTariq.thats  enough.thanks

Comment: If you want a Javascript solution, then please update the tags on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can give some basic idea.

add class name to those have links from external link download file like below .Here i named as `externalFile`

```
 <a  class="externalFile" href="http://127.0.0.1:8005/storage/dummy.pdf" class="badge badge-primary" style="width:100%;padding:10px;font-size:12px;margin-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
```

then in ajax script.Find all download link and send it to server.

```
$(function (){
    var links = [];
    $(".externalFile").each(function ()
    {
        links.push(this.href);
    });
  
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{url('ajax')}}",
        data:{
            links:links,
            "_token":"{{csrf_token()}}"
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
           if(data.failure){
               $.each(data.failure,function (key,links){
                   $("a[href='"+links+"']").hide()
               })
           }
        }
    });
})
```

Then in server side

```
Route::any("ajax", function (Request  $request) {


    $linkList=[];
    foreach ($request->links as $value){
        $client=Http::get($value);
        if($client->status()==200){
            $linkList['sucess'][]=$value;

        } else{
            $linkList['failure'][]=$value;
        }
    }

    return $linkList;
});
```

`Note:`i dont say this is an elegant way to do it.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a complete few lines code that I should replace with the above code that I pasted in my question. My knowledge of PHP is Zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
$file = "https://www.externaldomain.com/downloads/".$book->slug.".pdf";//EXTERNAL LINK
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $file_exists = false;
}
else {
    $file_exists = true;
}
@endphp

@if($file_exists)
<a href="EXTERNAL_LINK">Download</a> //Download button
@endif
```